SQL login using Azure Token failed
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $ExeDatabase -AccessToken $AccessToken -query "CREATE USER [$Appowner] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER"


Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user ''.
At line:1 char:1

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $ExeDatabase


How to resolve this error?
I tried running from Jump server and to run query.

How do you acquire the access token?

Have you read the Invoke-Sqlcmd online help yet? There are several hints about prerequisites for authentication with access tokens.

Please check if your access token is still valid. Get a new access token and give it a try. Access token is time-bound, and can expire in an hour.


Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user

The access token which you have provided may be incorrect or the access token is not authorized to access the database, that may be the reason to get login failed error. Ensure the user or managed identity that which you are trying to acquire access token is having permission to access database. Along with that ensure your access token is not expired. Use below PowerShell command to acquire access token:
az account get-access-token --resource https://database.windows.net/

Use below PowerShell command to run the query in SQL database:
$AccessToken = (az account get-access-token --resource https://database.windows.net/ | ConvertFrom-Json).accessToken
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance <serverName>.database.windows.net -Database <dbName> -AccessToken $AccessToken -Query "CREATE USER [appName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER"

It will run successfully as shown below:

And the use will create in the database successfully as shown below:

